# Webview opens chrome tab

Tags: android, webview

I've been trying this code from this tutorial: https://amatellanes.wordpress.com/2013/06/01/android-ejemplo-de-webview-en-android-parte-1/ but every time I run the application, it opens a new browser with chrome's top menu. I don't want to display that menu, just the web page.

My activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks,

Comment: What does "with chrome's top menu" mean? Do you want to hide the top app bar?

Comment: You can not remove bar having "Menu" as it is part of webpage you are loading. Where as in order to remove bar showing "EjemploWebView" make the app in full screen by adding following line in onCreate() method                   getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
          View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE)

Comment: I don't want to open chrome. My app works like a bookmark and I want to see that link into that WebView without open chrome's app.

Comment: You might be using Intent in order to open it in browser (might be something like this) `Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);`     Instead pass on the URL to the web view as suggested in the example link you had given.

Comment: I was working on a similar project and I solved the problem. It was my fault, the code url has not www... When I put the www.direction it worked. I have defined a redirection url without www to one with it. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a wrong url. Because my web has not www but it has a redirection to a www direction url. So I changed the url for the one with www.